# Possible to pull Insights data via Instagram API?

Tags: instagram-api

Instagram recently allowed accounts to link to a Facebook Business Page. They also added a new 'Insights' section that gives metrics like:

Impressions
Reach
Top Posts
Followers by Age

[image]

I can't find a way to pull these new numbers in via the API. Is there a separate Analytics API that I need to apply for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick update for this question: the Instagram Platform API now offers [an endpoint for insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media#insights).

**Endpoint**

```
GET graph.facebook.com
    /{media_id}/insights?metric={engagement|impressions|reach|saved|video_views}
```

**Example**

```
GET graph.facebook.com
    /17895695668004550/insights?metric=impressions,reach
```

**Example Response**

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "impressions",
      "period": "lifetime",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 264
        }
      ],
      "title": "Impressions",
      "description": "Total number of times the media object has been seen",
      "id": "17855590849148465/insights/impressions/lifetime"
    },
    {
      "name": "reach",
      "period": "lifetime",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 103
        }
      ],
      "title": "Reach",
      "description": "Total number of unique accounts that have seen the media object",
      "id": "17855590849148465/insights/reach/lifetime"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Having faced this very problem (analytics being confined to the mobile app), I decided to use the Android app [SSL Packet Capture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture&hl=en) (NO root required) to capture the requests (you must manually fetch a post's insights in the app whilst recording).  The correct GET request will be listed inside one of the Instagram entries and it's long!

The necessary access token is already embedded in the request and the instagram post id can be substituted to fetch post-level analytics: Reach, Impressions & Engagement.  Moreover the GET request **must be made over https**.

The request (in URL decoded form) will look something like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/graphql?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&query_id=<QUERY_ID>&locale=en_US&strip_nulls=true&strip_defaults=true&querparams={"0":{"id":"<POST_ID>", "access_token":"<ACCESS_TOKEN_2>:{"_token_ver":2,"_auth_user_id":<USER_ID>,"_token":"<TOKEN>","asns":{"<ASNS>,"time":1476466064},"_auth_user_backend":"accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend","last_refreshed":1476396104.372065,"_platform":1,"_auth_user_hash":""}"}}'
```

Comment: any ideas on what queryId, accessToken2, token (again), and asns parameters would be?

Comment: Well the parameters will be unique to your Instagram app and as I mentioned above they will already be embedded in the captured request.  For what it's worth I've found that these access tokens don't expire whereas the public API tokens have done so many times.

Comment: Great suggestion jpryda, but after installing hte SSL Packet Capture on my phone, and running instagram I always get a Network request encoutered error HTTP HTTP_TRANSPORT_ERROR: AsyncSocketException: error: 14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certicifate verify failed, type = SSL error. Any Ideas I guess it might have something to do with the certificate.