# Sniffing http then using python requests to make same call

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests, instagram

Instagram insights isn't offered on desktop so in order to get round this I set up mitm proxy and have sniffed the http requests that take place between instagram and my phone when I log in to insights.

[image: This is the post request made to login]

How do I re-engineer this so I can use the same command with the requests library in Python?
This is what I've tried so far... but I keep getting a 'failed' due to not being logged in.

```
import json

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
payload = {"username":"souXXX","password":"XXXX","_csrftoken":"XXXXXXn2fIQfrQXXXXXn"}


r = requests.post("https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/login/", data=payload, headers=headers)
```

I've spent aaaages trying to get this work, and I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. As such, I'd love some advice/guidance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code obviously does not match the request you've captured in the proxy. You need to fix that.

Comment: That's sort of what I'm asking for help with. I've used the same URL that is captured in the proxy and I've added in the auth data such as username/password and csrftoken. What am I missing?

Comment: to be sure instagram dont want you do this. they would much prefer you use the sandbox API. https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Comment: Hi Puton - the problem is they don't offer an insights API via desktop. As such, I'm trying to reverse engineer the get requests so I can pull the relevant data on organic posts (such as reach) and carry out any analysis.

Comment: why not just use the facebook insights api?

Comment: You only have access to paid Instagram metrics with Facebook insights API. Not organic, and unfortunately I need organic impressions/reach- I believe this is the only way. It's frustrating, and I've spent so much time on it I want to obtain a solution now ha!

Comment: @HarryRobinson see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707910/possible-to-pull-insights-data-via-instagram-api maybe using a different tool that gives you back the full request url would be more helpful

Comment: Thanks Puton - that's the post I found originally that lead me down the path of using a http proxy. Perhaps you're right that mitm is a bit too abstracted for my understanding and a different sniffer would be more useful.

Comment: Perhaps you should check the mitmproxy docs? There's a form submitted in that request with two parameters and data additional to the JSON. You've just pulled out the JSON for some reason. That's like if I asked you say 'Robotron 2048' and you said 'ron' and then insisted that's what I asked. And then there are the headers...

Comment: It's not clear what you're confused about, is the mitmproxy screen itself unclear? Form submission? You can also dump out the request in various other forms, if it will help. That 'signature' blob should give you pause too, if you see it on every payload in the flow. It would suggest the client signs the payload with a secret you don't have easy access to.

Comment: Thanks Pvt. Appreciate the guidance - what I was confused by was trying to reconstruct the get request. I think it might be as you suggested - there's a payload with a secret I don't have access to and obtaining this is well outside my knowledge.

Comment: Fundamentally, the thing I'm confused about though  is reconstructing the 'raw' get request. I.e. Given that screenshot of the various headers and what not how one would create the same request using the requests library

Comment: They sign the form.  Submitting a raw dictionary as the data won't be accepted by their api. If you somehow figure out how to sign the form the same way the app does so that Instagram believes it's the app making the request then you'd likely be able to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks B.Adler - could you point out the part that is the signed part of the form? This has given me some direction though, so again, thanks for that!